Gradle Unable to Resolve Plugin Despite Successful Curl Request
I am encountering an issue with Gradle when attempting to run a task on a Linux server. Despite having the correct Java and Gradle versions configured, I am getting SSL misconfiguration errors when Gradle tries to resolve plugins. Here's a detailed breakdown of my setup and the error:
Environment:
Gradle version: 8.8
Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_412"
Java home: Set in /etc/profile as
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.412.b08-2.el8.x86_64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.github.node-gradle.node' version '2.2.0'
    id 'com.marklogic.ml-gradle' version '4.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://developer.marklogic.com/maven2/'
    }
}

configurations {
    mlcp
}

dependencies {
    mlcp 'com.marklogic:mlcp:10.0.9.2'
    mlcp files('lib')
}

node {
    version = '10.5.0'
    npmVersion = '6.1.0'
    download = true
}

Error when running following command
**./gradlew taskname -PmlHost="localhost" on the linux server, getting following error : **
2024-06-07T18:10:27.221+0000 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://plugins.gradle.org:443
2024-06-07T18:10:27.224+0000 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to plugins.gradle.org/ip:443
2024-06-07T18:10:27.224+0000 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to plugins.gradle.org/ip:443 with timeout 30000
> Could not resolve com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:2.2.0.
   > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/2.2.0/gradle-node-plugin-2.2.0.pom'.
      > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/2.2.0/gradle-node-plugin-2.2.0.pom'.
         > Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
            > Connect to plugins.gradle.org:443 [plugins.gradle.org/104.16.72.101, plugins.gradle.org/i.p, plugins.gradle.org/2606:4700:0:0:0:0:6810:4865, plugins.gradle.org/2606:4700:0:0:0:0:6810:4965] failed: Network is unreachable (connect failed)

However, when I use curl to check the connection, I get a 200 OK response:
curl -I "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/2.2.0/gradle-node-plugin-2.2.0.pom"

and same code when I am running on my local system it is work fine
There I am using java version "1.8.0_202"
Why does Gradle fail to resolve the plugin due to an SSL misconfiguration even though curl works fine? How can I resolve this SSL misconfiguration to allow Gradle to successfully connect to the plugin repository?
Any help or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated!
